# How to completely disable Yammer chat?

Tags: yammer

Is there a possibility to completely disable Yammer chat, or at least be set so that users see only a network user from the same group?

I want users to talk to each other within a group permit. Outside the group the members should not be awailable for other group members.

Here's an example:

Group A: User A1, User A2
Group B: User B1, User B2

A1 and A2 should see eachother in chat, but not be allowed to see user B1 and B2

B1 and B2 should see eachother in chat, but not be allowed to see user A1 and A2

Answer (score 0):

This type of customization is not possible in Yammer. Yammer by design 'is built around open communication so team members can get up to speed, have greater context around the work they are doing, and make better decisions.'

Restricting in the way you described is not possible.